# Does the lib get bundled in APK

Tags: android, dalvik

I have added a libs folder to my project root and the libs contain two jar files. When I compile the  source, I get the APK created. When I unzip the APK, I cannot see the libs folder in it? Why this behavoir, as I believe libs should be bundled with APK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you include a `jar` then a relevant code from there gets transformed into bytecode the same as your own code and it all becomes a single `dex` file within `apk`.
It is native `*.so` libraries which you create in C/C++ with the NDK for your project they get bundled into your apk as `*.so` files. Because they are not in Java.

Answer (score 2):

I believe all necessary classes are put in dex file(Dalvik VM executable).